# Nginx + ssl not responding

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm currently putting up a server with SSL for leapfunder.

I created a server (Ubuntu 14.04 on AWS), directed notes.civocracy.org to it. I bought a SSL certificate on GoDaddy, lauched and configure a Nginx server.
But whenever I go to https://notes.civocracy.org/, I get no response.

I don't understand why, because Nginx is running and listening, there is no firewall I know about.

My nginx config :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name notes.civocracy.org;

        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/civocracy.key;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

I generated civocracy.key on the server.
bundle.crt is the merge of the 2 .crt files GoDaddy gave me.
Now there is no error message, so I don't know how to look from now on.

Some people look like they had the router not forwarding correctly to the 443 port, but I'm on an EC2 instance, so I don't think it applies

Comment: A `dig notes.civocracy.org` shows the subdomain pointing (via CNAME) at `webredir.vip.gandi.net`, not an EC2 IP. Are you sure you have your DNS set up properly?

Comment: Did you check the [security group(s)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule) you have assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, because http://notes.civocracy.org points correctly to the nginx page

Comment: @DerfK : The security groups is supposed to be "allow everything" :
`Ports Protocol Source all open
All All 0.0.0.0/0 ✔`

Comment: @ceejayoz Because if I put my server down I don't get the webpage. You do not see it because I used a "hidden web forwarding" on Gandi. But you might have a really good point there, maybe the problem comes from this redirection?

Comment: Yes, the problem comes from the redirection. You need to either use a `CNAME` to `ec2-52-7-151-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com` or an `A` to `52.7.151.160`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS is not set up properly. It appears you're using some sort of Gandi service (maybe [this](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/domains/management/domain-as-website/forwarding#forwarding_address)?) to present your EC2 server in an invisible iframe.

`notes.civocracy.org` is **not** pointed at an EC2 server. It's pointed at `webredir.vip.gandi.net`, which appears to be some sort of redirection service. The HTML of the page they're serving is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>notes.civocracy.org</title>
  </head>
  <frameset>
    <frame src="http://ec2-52-7-151-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com" name="redir">
    <noframes>
      <p>Original location:
        <a href="http://ec2-52-7-151-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com">http://ec2-52-7-151-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com</a>
      </p>
    </noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Your A record should be pointed at that EC2 instance, `52.7.151.160`. Gandi's redirection service doesn't have HTTPS set up, which is why it's not responding. `https://ec2-52-7-151-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` presents your SSL certificate and nginx configuration.

Comment: Modifying my DNS, I give you the answer soon ;)

Comment: @NicolasReynolds Note: the fairly lengthy TTL on the records (3 hours) means it may take a while to see the changes.